# How to refresh the page in php after displaying alert

Tags: javascript, php

I am updating the records using php/mysql. and after all is done .
 I run this code for user confirmation about the activity.

```
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("We Have credited your account")';
        echo '</script>';
```

How Do i refresh the page so that once user clicks ok, it will refresh all the details again and should display users with new values from the db.

If I use this right after the alert.

```
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

It does not displays the alert message and simply refreshes the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alerts are weird but you can do something like the below as your echo. Alert returns an undefined.

```
echo "<script language='javascript'>";
echo "if(!alert('We Have credited your account')){
    window.location.reload();
}";
echo "</script>";
```

**UPDATE**

Right after posting this I realized that the `alert` will block any other js from running. You can literally just do

```
echo "<script language='javascript'>";
echo 'alert("We Have credited your account");';
echo 'window.location.reload();';
echo "</script>";
```

Edit to handle page refresh (submit by OP):

```
echo "<script language='javascript'>";
echo 'alert("We Have credited your account");';
echo 'window.location.reload();';
echo "</script>";
} else {
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Please Paste Exact URL Here")';
    echo '</script>';  
}
```

Comment: or perhaps you can advice any other method .. to display confirmation to user and then refresh the page ???

Comment: Might have been a quote issue but see the update as well. You can use the `confirm` as well but that lets the user confirm or cancel and I am not sure that is what you want...

Comment: i just need to inform user ... no cancel.. i am trying the new code.will updat here

Comment: does not work either .. alert("We Have credited your account")window.location.reload( ..  this is what it displays again

Comment: `alert()` will always block every other javascript from running. no matter if you are echo-ing with PHP or not.

Comment: @moonakhan You were missing a semi-colon on the alert statement. Add that and it appear to run. The issue is you now have a loop of alert and reload.

Comment: can you please update your answer again. ... I have copied the same stuff that you have written,

Comment: I have and tested both which appear to be working. Another thing to note is that `header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` has to be before any output see http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: do i need to place this code with in <script> </script> ,, if yes, please place the whole code ..

Comment: sorry for last comment. as i dnt know anything abt js

Comment: You're all good. Yes you would need them and I added it to the code. You will need to find a way to avoid a loop though.

Comment: @moonakhan awesome just tweaked it a bit. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.reload` and `header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` will keep you in a loop "basically" not static "locations", if you die in game you get reloaded to a point or location, you can't replace where you spawn until you got past that point (^.^).

Use window.location.replace("your_page.php") or window.location.href = "your_page.php"; because reload and header is more used for auto redirection to different locations while replace and href is more used to "escape" your current page and load it from scratch.

So do something like this if your query passes:

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "<script language='javascript'>";
echo 'alert("Your alert msg");';
echo 'window.location.replace("your_page.php");';
echo "</script>";

}
else{ 
    echo "FAIL";
}
```

It will prevent data insertion or strings from going in a loop over and over again. I had a pc's USB ports that malfunctioned once and it kept on inserting and alerting in on of my databases it was an EPIC disaster took a while cleaning it up.